# Passing Form Type to a method returns null reference?

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, object-reference

I have a method which is something like this:

```
    public void Report(Form form, string[] textboxes, string[] patientdetails)
    {
        try
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (string textbox in textboxes)
            {
                form.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().FirstOrDefault(n => n.Name == textbox).Text = patientdetails[i];
                i++;
            }

            form.ShowDialog();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

by passing arguments to these return object refrence not set to an instance object:

```
 string[] textboxes = new string[] { "txtPatientName", "txtAge", "txtGender","txtTestType","txtDate" }; 
 string[] patientDetails = new string[]{"Ammar Bashir", "19", "Male", "White Blood Cell Test", "12 March , 2013"};

 //Test a winform which contain textboxes.
  Report(Test, textboxes, patientDetails);
```

Comment: Debug that code a bit and tell us where the problem actually is. I'm guessing that `FirstOrDefault(n => n.Name == textbox)` is returning null for one of those textbox names.

Comment: It means it didn't find a textboxes on a form which is passed as a parameter and yes thats line of code which is throwing exception.

Comment: Right... so why is there a mismatch between the strings and what is on the form?

Comment: On form there are five textbox controls with names of string[] textboxes but when I am trying to do this on event directly its working good and i dont know how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it , Actually all the textboxes were in first splitterPanel of splitContainer, I traversse through them with their 'Controls' property and changed the Text property of TextBoxes...Guys thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of your code or knowing exactly what line the exception was thrown by, I'm guessing that you didn't initialize `Test` before passing it to the method.

Either that, or

```
 form.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().FirstOrDefault(n => n.Name == textbox)
```

Is not finding a match and therefore returning `null`. You then call `Text` on `null` which would throw the exception.

Comment: Test is a winform class which has been already intialized when passed to a method.

Comment: When Iam doing same way without method it works perfectly..But dont know why as passing parameters returns null.